# Customize Grafana bar chart

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I’m very new to Grafana but I like it!

Now I try to customize my bar chart. Right now it looks like this:

[image: Simple bar chart]

I would like to do two changes:

1. Increase size of names on the left side
2. Setup the bar chat out of small images like that?

[image: Improved bar chart]

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian Buster and a MariaDB SQL database.